# can't return a date from a firebase cloud function?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to simply return a date from a firebase function:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

const date = functions.https.onCall(() => {
  return {
    date: new Date(),
    iso: new Date().toISOString()
  };
});
export default date;
```

But here's the result I'm getting (using firebase functions:shell):

```
RESPONSE RECEIVED FROM FUNCTION: 200, {
  "result": {
    "date": {},
    "iso": "2018-12-08T18:00:20.794Z"
  }
}
```

Note that the Date() object is being serialized as an empty object which seems wrong? I would have expected at least a .toString() or something of the Date instance...

Does this mean I have to explicitly avoid returning Date instances? I can write a custom serializer which I wrap around my functions to deeply convert Date instances to strings via .toISODate() etc but that seems like I must be missing something!

THanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have a date object `d`, you should either:

1. Send its unix epoch time in milliseconds with [`d.getTime()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp), or
2. Send it JSON serialized form with [`d.toJSON()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tojson.asp).

I suggest #1, as it's easier to interop with different systems.  Every system understands dates in unix epoch time, and that number doesn't require parsing.

Comment: Thanks. I've ended up building a recursive serializer which walks any response objects and converts Dates to their ISO (string) representation, but your epoch time would be great, too.

For me, the confusion was getting an empty object just by returning a Date instance -- I'd humbly offer that that behavior violates the "fewest surprises" principle!

Closing.

Comment: I feel like this should have been more clearly mentioned in the docs, I've lost quite some time on debugging why I could not send back a date. Especially when the client can send a Date just fine to the cloud function.